# Transferring a dart library to another owner in pub.dartlang.org

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Since pub uses my identity for the publish, how would I go about transferring control to someone else, yet still allow them to publish releases to the same project?  Maybe this is trivial; I've never tried it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `pub uploader [options] {add/remove} <email>`.

Once the new uploader added, you can remove yourself.

```
pub uploader add <new-owner-email>
pub uploader remove <old-owner-email>
```

---

```
$ pub uploader -h

Manage uploaders for a package on pub.dartlang.org.

Usage: pub uploader [options] {add/remove} <email>
-h, --help       Print usage information for this command.
    --server     The package server on which the package is hosted.
                 (defaults to "https://pub.dartlang.org")

    --package    The package whose uploaders will be modified.
                 (defaults to the current package)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what i've been looking for!

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** It is now possible to invite new uploaders using the *admin tab* on the package page on `pub.dev` website.

[image: Inviting an uploader]